# Union of balls is convex

Tags: real-analysis

Given $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, Let $B(X;\varepsilon)$ be the union of $B(x;\varepsilon)$ (balls with center in $x \in X$ and radius $\varepsilon$).

Show that if X is convex, then $B(X;\varepsilon)$ is convex.

I see that if two elements $x,y$ are inside the same ball, then I have the line segment that connects $x$ and $y$ all inside that ball, because all balls inside $\mathbb{R}^n$ are convex.

But I don't know how to proceed if they aren't inside the same ball.

Any tips?

Comment: Don't you mean $X\subset \mathbb R^n$, rather than $\in$?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x,y\in B(X,\epsilon)$. By definition there are $x_0,y_0\in X$ such that $||x-x_0||<\epsilon$ and $||y-y_0||<\epsilon$. Now let $t\in (0,1)$. We have to show that the point $(1-t)x+ty$ is in $B(X,\epsilon)$ as well. Now, since $X$ is convex we know that $(1-t)x_0+ty_0\in X$. Also:

$||((1-t)x+ty)-((1-t)x_0+ty_0)||=||(1-t)(x-x_0)+t(y-y_0)||\leq $

$\leq(1-t)||x-x_0||+t||y-y_0||<(1-t)\epsilon+t\epsilon=\epsilon$

So $(1-t)x+ty\in B((1-t)x_0+ty_0,\epsilon)\subseteq B(X,\epsilon)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact your $B(X,\varepsilon)$ is the [**Minkowski addition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) $X \oplus B(0,\varepsilon)$ of the convex sets $X$ and $B(0,\varepsilon)$ (ball centered in $0$ with radius $\varepsilon$).

In this context, the answer is immediate: there is a classical theorem (given in the Wikipedia reference) saying that the Minkowski addition of 2 convex sets is itself convex.